# R datatable row padding size modification

Tags: css, r, shiny, datatable, shinyjs

I have a small R shiny app
https://kormir.shinyapps.io/dt_test/

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
            column(4,
                   br(),
                   br(),
                   dataTableOutput('dt1')
                   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$dt1 <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(mtcars[1:4,1:4])
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In uses the datatable package to create dynamic tables.
I would like to reduce the internal paddings but by css skills aren't good enough to do so.

[image]

I need to remove that yellow area or make it very very small.
For instance I figured out the class of the rows and tried to force the size of these paddings to 0.

```
 .odd {
    background-color: red!important;
    border-collapse: collapse!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    border : 0px !important;
}
```

It does not work...

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit

*My initial solution did not account for the interactive changes to the table while in session. The following js injection upon DataTables initialization `function(){$('tbody td').css({'padding': '0px'});}` applies the padding change to the initial state of the table but any changes such as sorting and pagination would cause the table to revert back to its initial display setting.*

How about injecting some javascript upon DataTables initialization with the [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) argument in [`Options`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/)?

For this, you must have the package [`htmlwidgets`](https://www.htmlwidgets.org) installed so you can use the `JS()` function. `JS()` treats strings as javascript code.

`DT::datatable()` has an [`options`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html) argument that corresponds to the `Options` in DataTables. `options` takes a list of named arguments in `DataTables` `Options`.

In `options`, supply a named list with the `initComplete` argument. In there, inject some js with `htmlwidgets::JS()` and the js callback will be executed upon your DataTables initialization.

DataTables has some [default styling options](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes), including one called `compact`. Here is what enabling the `compact` styling option does (quote from [here](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes)):

> Reduce the amount of white-space the default styling for the DataTable uses, increasing the information density on screen

OK, so next step is to add the class `compact` to your DataTables object in the DOM like so:

The js portion that matters is:

`function(){$(this).addClass('compact');}`

`$(...)` is [jQuery's](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp) syntax to access elements in the DOM. What goes inside `$(...)` is the selector of the DOM element you want to select. Fortunately, because you are injecting this js code in the DataTables event, you can use the `this` selector to refer to the table. The next method is `addClass()`. It does what it says: it adds a class to the selected object in the DOM. You want to add the class `compact` to your table and then DataTables will take care of the rest.

Ok, here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(4,
         br(),
         br(),
         dataTableOutput('dt1')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$dt1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars, 
              options = list(
                initComplete = JS(
                  "function(){$(this).addClass('compact');}")
              )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

Result:
[image]

After changing pagination and sorted by `cyl`:

[image]

`compact` styling still applies.

Comment: Elegant example showing the power of injecting JS this way!

Comment: There is a problem. See the app now with the DT having multiple pages.
If you change page, the formatting is gone.

https://kormir.shinyapps.io/dt_test/

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you.